# ajax + servlet country state city list

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to populate city, country and statelist using ajax, and servlets.
Now I know how to get the XMLhttpRequest object. There is a standard mechanism to do that and depending on the cross browser compatibility, you do get a ActiveX or a xml object..

Then you send a request to the *actionservlet*, using `xmlhttprequest.open()` and you send the request and you have an event handler function to take care of onreadystatechange issue, Now, when it comes to receiving the response, I get an error stating that the response is not completely received, i.e the status `!= 4`... now.

I was wondering, how does the entire mechanism work..

how to put the parameters in the request, send it to servlet, and then I know how to retreieve the param from the URL.. but then how to send a valid response...??

I am confused on the ajax part, because I am not using / not use PHP. It is harder to think. Please suggest what should be done.

Is there any easier way to populate a city, country and state list??

Comment: Not using PHP shouldn't matter at all, just make sure the service you call (on the same domain) responds a valid XML document with the correct Content-Type header. (or if you use JSON, a valid one of those with the correct JSON Content-Type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let the servlet return the desired dropdown options in the desired format based on the request parameters in the `doGet()` method. Here's an example which returns it in JSON format with help of [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String type = request.getParameter("type"); // Returns "country" or "state".
    String value = request.getParameter("value"); // Value of selected country or state.
    Map<String, String> options = optionDAO.find(type, id); // Do your thing to obtain them from DB. Map key is option value and map value is option label.
    String json = new Gson().toJson(options); // Convert Java object to JSON string.

    response.setContentType("application/json"); // Inform client that you're returning JSON.
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // Important if you want world domination.
    response.getWriter().write(json); // Write JSON string to response.
}
```

Assuming that the above servlet is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/options`, you could use it as in the following JSP example with help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com). I am recommending jQuery because you would otherwise end up with 10 times as much JavaScript code needed for this "simple" task.

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 3983929</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#country').change(function() { fillOptions('state'); });
                $('#state').change(function() { fillOptions('city'); });
            });
            function fillOptions(dropdownId) {
                var dropdown = $('#' + dropdownId);
                $.getJSON('options?type=' + dropdownId + '&value=' + $(this).val(), function(opts) {
                    $('>option', dropdown).remove(); // Clean old options first.
                    if (opts) {
                        $.each(opts, function(key, value) {
                            dropdown.append($('<option/>').val(key).text(value));
                        });
                    } else {
                        dropdown.append($('<option/>').text('Please select ' + dropdownId));
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select id="country" name="country">
                <c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
                    <option value="${country.key}" ${param.country == option.key ? 'selected' : ''}>${country.value}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <select id="state" name="state">
                <option>Please select country</option>
            </select>
            <select id="city" name="city">
                <option>Please select state</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Here I am assuming that you've already prepopulated the `${countries}` as being a `Map<String, String>` in a servlet which has preprocessed the request to this JSP for the initial display.*