# How to populate dependent combobox in jsp with mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, combobox

I have registration form jsp page that calls a servlet to add data to mysql database. In the same page I have 2 dropdowns, First one is country which is hard-coded.

According to the selected value, second combobox should populate with the appropriate `city_name` values before submit the form.

But I can't use php here.

```
table1-->user(fname,lname,country,city_id)  
table2-->city(city_id,city_name,country)
```

HTML,

```
<form role="form" name="form1" action="Registration" method="post" class="signup-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select 
          onchange="document.getElementById('country').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; document.getElementById('idValue').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
            <option></option>
            <option value="sl">Sri Lanka</option>
            <option value="jp">Japan</option>
            <option value="en">England</option>
            <option value="kr">Korea</option>
            <option value="us">USA</option>
        </select>
        <input name="country" placeholder="Select Your Country" id="country" onfocus="this.select()" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="city" name="city" class="form-control">
            <option>--Select--</option>
        </select>
        <label id="city1" class="input-group-error form-error"></label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use backticks (`\``) for keywords.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ajax + servlet country state city list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983929/ajax-servlet-country-state-city-list)